# How to access parameters passed in the __init__ in property attribute?

Tags: python

```
class Data(object):
  def __init__(self, info_dict):
    self.name = info_dict["name"]
    self.address = info_dict["address"]
    self._url = None

 @property
 def url(self):
   if 'my_url' in info_dict:
      self._url = info_dict['my_url']
   elif 'this_url' in info_dict:
      self._url = info_dict['this_url']
   return self._url
```

This is the sample input passed to the object

```
info_dict = {"name" :"myname", "address" : "myaddress", "my_url" : "http://sdsf"}
another_info_dict = {"name" :"myname", "address" : "myaddress", "this_url" : "http://sdsf"}
```

As you can see the  url in dictionary comes with two different key **my_url** and **this_url**. So I using url property to set the url regardless of key.

Now the problem is info_dict passed in the **init** function cannot be accessed in the @property url method and I don't want to **create instance variable info_dict** and access it in url property. Is there a way to pass it to url property? You can suggest me any cleaner way to do this.

Comment: There's not a way to do this. You need to either assign `info_dict` to a property in `__init__`, or set the two possible urls in `__init__`. The dictionary doesn't exist in the scope of the class once you exit the `__init__` function.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of `__init__`, `info_dict` is a local variable. Once `__init__` is done, the variable goes away.

The simplest solution is to simply not use the property. 
Just move the logic into `__init__` and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: This has the added benefit of only having to run the logic once (when the instance is initialized), rather than every time you access the `url` property.

Answer (score 0):

When I have two possible dictionary keys that might store a value I want, I always use a `try` `except` block.

```
try:
    self._url = info_dict['my_url']
except KeyError:
    self._url = info_dict['this_url']
```